# Cassandra how to add to an integer field?

Tags: php, cassandra

I'm trying to use cassandra to store view counts that i am parsing from some log files

Is there a way to do views => views + 343 or something along those lines? i don't want to have to query first because that will slow down my script quite a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cassandra support native counters; you will need to declare the default validation class (ie the default value type) as CounterColumnType:

`create column family counterCF with default_validation_class=CounterColumnType;`

Then you should be able to do CQL operations like:

`UPDATE counterCF SET X = X + N WHERE key = K;`

Comment: Is there a way to do an insert that falls back to an update if the key already exists?

Comment: In Cassandra, I'm afraid not.  You want to design you datamodel such that inserts are idempotent, eg using uuids for columns names etc.  This will also allow you to retry should the operation fail.